# Why Office365 OAuth2 refresh token expires when password changes?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ms-office, office365

I'm testing the use of OAuth2 for MS Office 365 in order to read calendar events, and just read the following in [this blog  post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx):

> ...the refresh token, while long living,
>   becomes invalid at some point too. One example is if the user changes
>   their password, refresh tokens become invalid.

From my experience with other OAuth2 providers, the refresh token should not expire when users change their passwords (isn't that one of the main purposes of the token - to allow password independent access?).

Am I missing something? What is the reason behind expiring the refresh tokens when password changes?

Answer (score 1):

A password change may happen after a password breach. Access & refresh tokens may have been issued during the time between the password breach and the detection, these tokens would need to be revoked as well as the password reset. To simplify administration of that - the exact time of the breach may be very hard to detect - all access is revoked and needs to be explicitly re-assigned by the Resource Owner.

Comment: Password breaches are only a fraction of all password changes. There are organizations in which the users are forced to change their password every few weeks.

Comment: Agree, but I believe MS wants to stay on the safe side for this one. I guess they could ask the user about a user-side breach and/or enforce it only if they know about a server-side breach.

Answer (score 0):

Normally users do not change their passwords without a reason. One of the reasons is that user might think his password might have been leaked. In such case it is not clear which of the refresh tokens (logins) are authentic and which are from a possible hacker.

Comment: I disagree. There are organizations in which there's a password change policy, which force users to change their password every few weeks. In that case they will also need to reconnect all apps.

Comment: Yes, enterprises often enforce pwd-change on a regular basis. But if they want you to change the password, I see it only logical that refresh tokens be revoked as well.